# Spring Boot load beans from context xml in library

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependencies

I have two applications:

- Application `child`: it's a Spring app with XML Schema-based configuration. So We have an `applicationContext.xml`.
- Application `parent`: Spring Boot app. Uses application `child` as a library.

Is possible to load all beans defined in `child` XML, and put them into `parent` context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

From [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html):

> As mentioned above, @Configuration classes may be declared as regular Spring  definitions within Spring XML files. **It is also possible to import Spring XML configuration files into @Configuration classes using the @ImportResource annotation**. Bean definitions imported from XML can be injected using @Autowired or @Import.

Here an example from the same javadoc that mix beans loaded from xml in beans defined in configuration class:

```
 @Configuration
 @ImportResource("classpath:/com/acme/database-config.xml")
 public class AppConfig {
     @Inject DataSource dataSource; // from XML

     @Bean
     public MyBean myBean() {
         // inject the XML-defined dataSource bean
         return new MyBean(this.dataSource);
     }
 }
```