# Spring boot xml bean initialization eagerly

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a similar requirement like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43072510/spring-boot-load-beans-from-context-xml-in-library). i.e. from my project, I am referring a library project through maven and initializing xml beans from this library project. But in my case, I have to initialize beans from multiple context files. I also have requirement to dynamically decide the name of context file like {dbName}Context.xml. I have to maintain right sequence for these files, and so I am initializing beans from all these files through code like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27580811/how-to-load-additional-bean-configuration-file-in-spring-at-run-time/27581446#27581446).

This works partially for me, it can initialize beans, but not eagerly. Beans initialized here lazily, even though in xml config, 'lazy-init' attribute is set to false.

Sample code:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig{
    @Autowired
    GenericApplicationContext context;

    @PostConstruct
    public void loadXmlContext() throws IOException {
        String dbName = getDatabaseName();

        Resource[] resources = getResourcesFromContext(
                "context1.xml",
                "context2.xml",
                dbName+"Context.xml",
                "context3.xml");

        XmlBeanDefinitionReader reader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(context);
        reader.setBeanClassLoader(context.getClassLoader());
        for (Resource r : resources) {
            reader.loadBeanDefinitions(r);
        }
    }

    private Resource[] getResourcesFromContext(String... contextFiles) throws IOException {
        PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver pmrl = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(context.getClassLoader());
        Resource[] resources = new Resource[0];

        for(String contextFile: contextFiles) {
            resources = ArrayUtils.addAll(resources, pmrl.getResources(contextFile));
        }
        return resources;
    }
}
```

**Question:** How to load beans from xml context files eagery in this case?

Comment: lazy-init attributes default value is false. When are you specifying context file? In application startup or in request?

Comment: Thanks, I am doing this on application startup. Updated the code in question.